# SQL Group by timing

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I have a table which has a column that I would like to group by, but only the last series of it (the table has a timestamp column to work with) For instance the table

```
Type | Time
=============
A    | 1:00
A    | 1:05
B    | 1:10
C    | 1:15
A    | 1:20
A    | 1:25
A    | 1:30
```

I would like to group these to do functions (Sum(), Max(), Avg()) on them with only getting the group before it is broken, so a standard group by Type will not work.

I would like something like:

```
Type | count_in_series | MinTime
================================
A    | 2               | 1:00
B    | 1               | 1:10
C    | 1               | 1:15
A    | 3               | 1:20
```

There is no way of knowing when the changes happen, the data given is just a sample to illustrate the point.

Is this possible?

***Solution***

I used this with concepts from answers below. Turns out the program I am using doesn't allow for variables or WITH CTE. Here is my solution using a sub query:

```
SELECT 
    Type
    , max(t_stamp) as maxTime
    , min(t_stamp) as minTime
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t_stamp desc) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY t_stamp desc) as grouping
    FROM MyTable) as t1
GROUP BY t1.grouping, t1.Type
ORDER BY min(t_stamp) desc
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: window function Lead() may help you if engine supports it.  If not, you could use user variables and assign row numbers and join on row_number + 1 = rowNumber and then compare T1.Type to T2.Type when same add count when different reset count.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh SQL express through an ignition client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you dont have `LAG`, you can use just `ROW_NUMBER()`

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/JXXB54702)

```
With CTE AS (
    SELECT T.*,           
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [TIME]) as ID,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY [TIME]) as rn
    FROM Table1 T       
)
SELECT [Type], COUNT(*) Count , MIN(Time) Time
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [Type], ID - rn
ORDER BY MIN(Time)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: The client I am using doesn't allow for variables or WITH CTE but using your concepts I came up with a solution using a sub query. Thank you, see my question edit for the solution I used

Answer (score 1):

You can use lag and row_number for getting correct bucket and then do group by as below:

```
;with cte as (
select *, Bucket = sum(sm) over (order by RowN) from (
select *,sm = case when (lag(type,1) over (order by [time]) <> [type]) then 1 else 0 end, 
    RowN= row_number() over(order by [time]) from #yourtime 
    ) a
    )
    select min([Type]) as [Type], count([Type]) as Count_in_Series, min([time]) as MinTime  from cte
    group by Bucket
```

Your output:

```
+------+-----------------+------------------+
| Type | Count_in_Series |     MinTime      |
+------+-----------------+------------------+
| A    |               2 | 01:00:00.0000000 |
| B    |               1 | 01:10:00.0000000 |
| C    |               1 | 01:15:00.0000000 |
| A    |               3 | 01:20:00.0000000 |
+------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Your input table:

```
create table #yourtime (type varchar(2), [Time] time)

insert into #yourtime ([type], [time]) values
 ('A','1:00')
,('A','1:05')
,('B','1:10')
,('C','1:15')
,('A','1:20')
,('A','1:25')
,('A','1:30')
```

Comment: Why you didnt use  use `OVER (order by [Time])` ??

Comment: I liked to take the input order on how it stored in the table as we require that sequence for lag

Comment: db tables are unordered dataset, you **cant** guaranted order unless you include `ORDER BY`, for example index and partitions can give you different results because data is stored differently..

Comment: Yep, i know that.. Here the requirement is to hold the order of first 2 A's in first bucket, then B, C and next 3 A's in 4th bucket then only we can do min and max accordingly... If I do order by time then we will loose this order, In actual scenario he might have a proper order on that column

Comment: Nope, if you order by time you get the OP required order. Two A's first and three at the end. Right now your answer is not deterministic. Because can provide different result based on how db store those rows. In the case OP doesnt provide an order you should ask for one.

Comment: It is deterministic because of final aggregation. But I got your point... Going by order by time is correct

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT 
  Type,
  count('Type'),
  min('Time')
FROM table
GROUP BY Type
```

----- edited -------
[Check this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb22c9/29)
If you can use user vars, that works:

```
SET @typeIndex = 1;

SELECT
  min(type) as type,
  count(type) as count,
  min(TIME_FORMAT(time, '%H %i')) as minTime
FROM(
  SELECT
  t.type, 
  t.time,
  (SELECT type FROM timeTest tt
        WHERE tt.time < t.time
        ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) as next_type,
  IF(type != (SELECT type FROM timeTest tt
        WHERE tt.time < t.time
        ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1), @typeIndex := @typeIndex+1, "" ) as t ,
  @typeIndex as tipeIndex
  FROM 
    timeTest t
) temp
GROUP BY temp.tipeIndex
```

Comment: Not quite: take a look at the 2 "A's" in the expected results.  basically count until type changes and then reset count. and show min time for each group.

Comment: The client I am using doesn't allow for variables or WITH CTE but I came up with a solution using a sub query. Thank you, see my question edit for the solution I used